# If $G$ acts non-trivially on a set then it has a proper normal subgroup of finite index

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

The following is an old exam question from a n introduction to group
theory course:

> Let $G$ be a group (possibly infinite) that acts non-trivially on a
>   finite set $X$ - that is there are $g\in G,x\in X$ s.t $g\cdot x\neq x$.
>
> Prove that there is a proper subgroup $N\trianglelefteq G$ of finite
>   index.

I didn't manage to get very far - Assume by contradiction that $G$
is simple, I know that the Kernel of the operation is normal in $G$
thus is is either $G$ or $\{e\}$ but since the action is non-trivial
the kernel of the operation is $\{e\}$ and the action is faithful.
- this is where I'm stuck.

Can someone please hint me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $G/Kernel$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $Sym(X).$ As $Sym(X)$ is finite we are done.